# Using JavaCV to display live image from camera

Tags: opencv, live, javacv

I am using JavaCV for on-the-fly image processing from a webcam.  It works great!  I can define a region of interest in the picture and crop every image before displaying and it'll still do a full 30 frames per second without problems.  Nice!

However, I'm using a CanvasFrame object to display the live image.  It works great (and easy), but is TOTALLY USELESS for including in an application.  I want to put the live image on a panel (or canvas or whatever) as one element of my application window.

The problem: A CanvasFrame lives in its own frame and disappears behind my window when my window gets focus, and also doesn't move when I move my window.

How can I get the live image onto an element that I can integrate with my normal UI elements?

Again, I need a replacement for CanvasFrame in JavaCV.  TIA.

Comment: Further testing.  Since the CanvasFrame object provides a getCanvas() method, I tried using it then putting the received Canvas into my UI.  However, that DID NOT WORK.  The Frame still pops up as a separate window with its canvas in it (and working), and the canvas on the UI stays blank.  So this DOES NOT SOLVE MY PROBLEM.  Any ideas?

Comment: Further testing.  Since the CanvasFrame object provides add() methods, I tried moving some of my UI elements into it (rather than the other way around).  This worked and the events were still processed even as the run() method continued.  However, I cannot setUndecorated (which I want to do) on a CanvasFrame.

Comment: I am now convinced the way I will solve this is to start with the source code of CanvasFrame, modify it so it can be undecorated and whatever else you need to modify (I've done this successfully), then make one of your modified CanvasFrames, and use it as a container for the entire UI (kind of the way you'd make container panels).  I'll report back my results.

Comment: Learn about [Drawing an Image with Java 2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) and do that for each image you get from the camera!

Answer (score 0):

I start a camera thread that grabs in a loop and draws on the CanvasFrame until a UI button is pressed.  THIS WORKS FINE.

In response to the UI button press, I stop the thread (which triggers grabber.stop).  Then I take the last image, and display that image on a panel.  THIS WORKS FINE (I know how to display an image, thanks).  I'd be done except CanvasFrame is a separate window which kinda sucks.

So instead I want to start a camera thread that grabs in a loop and does NOT draw on a CanvasFrame.  Instead it just keeps an internal copy of the last image.  Then to display on my UI, I set a timer (which fires correctly) and just display the latest image on my panel.  THIS DOES NOT WORK--the panel remains blank.  And yet, how is this case any different from the case that works?  The only difference is that the grabber in the camera thread has not been stopped yet.  It's fine when the camera is NOT in its grabbing loop, but will NOT display when it is looping.  And I'm careful to make cvCopy's of the images I pass to the UI, so there's no problem with contention for the memory.

I will also say that displaying on the CanvasFrame in a loop seems to trigger my Logitech C920 auto-focus, whereas just grabbing a single image and displaying it (which I can do easily as long as the grabber is stopped) does NOT seem to auto-focus.

The upshot is CanvasFrame seems to be doing lots of tricky stuff in the backgraound which cannot be matched by just having grabber.start, grabber.grab, grabber.stop, then display on your own panel.

Sam, I've seen your name in the CanvasFrame source code, so you should know better than anyone what's the difference between my 2 scenarios.

Comment: OK, I see my mistakenly commented out repaint.  I can paint the image fine EVEN WHILE THE grabber is started (but not stopped) in another thread.    ======    ======    So you can paint it on your own UI elements just as CanvasFrame does on its own.  Thanks Sam, your fine work on the library is good--I'm doing quite complicated processing on every frame and can still do it faster than the camera can provide them: 30+ fps.  Sometimes I actually process the same frame twice because the camera thread can't keep up with the JavaCV code!  NICE.  Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, and Auto-focus in Logitech C920 does work regardless of what element is displaying it, so it works fine because the hardware/driver combo deals with it before even handing over the image.  It's not the best auto-focus in the world, but any AF can have a hard time--pouring on more light helps.

Comment: Well anyway, if `CanvasFrame` displays like you want it, have you tried to simply do something similar in whatever `Frame` you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a replacement for CanvasFrame that can be used in any UI and now I have one.  Here it is, a swing element that can display a live (or still) image:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CamImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public CamImagePanel() {
        super();
        // Note that at this point, image = null
        // so be sure to call setImage() before setVisible(true)
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null)      // Not efficient, but safer.
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage img) {
        image = img;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Then, I set a timer in my main event thread to wake up 20 to 30 times per second (30-50 ms) and in the alarm callback method, I simply call mypanel.setImage(latestPhoto); and it's just like a live image.

I have a controller object with it's own thread which fills a buffer with an image from the camera as fast as it can, and I just ask the controller for the latest image.  This way, synchronizing isn't required, I can actually ask for the images faster or slower than the camera can make them, and my logic still works fine.

A button on the UI stops the timer and I can leave up the final image on the panel or take the panel down completely with setVisible(false).

Comment: Note that the main thread could do the grabber.grab() itself, instead of using a separate thread.  Remember grab() is a blocking read, which might be a problem for some systems.  Using a separate thread will not work if you use an algorithm that relies on differences between subsequent frames since without synchronization, the 2 frames you grab might actually be a single frame from the camera.